# kvoptions is missing from texlive 2014

Tags: texlive, kvoptions

I upgraded from texlive 2007 to texlive 2014 on my Mac OS X.  Now source files that previously compiled fine give the error messages below.  I looked at the previous question suggesting to do "tlmgr install oberdiek" and I did that, but these same errors still happen.

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 4835, version
               `2010/09/13' of package ifpdf,
               but only version
               `2007/12/12 v1.6 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)'
               is available.

)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 2345, version
               `2010/04/08' of package infwarerr,
               but only version
               `2007/09/09 v1.2 Providing info/warning/message (HO)'
               is available.

)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 125, version
               `2010/04/08' of package infwarerr,
               but only version
               `2007/09/09 v1.2 Providing info/warning/message (HO)'
               is available.

(/Users/stmv/Library/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 134, version
               `2009/12/14' of package auxhook,
               but only version
               `2007/04/06 v1.1 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)'
               is available.

(/Users/stmv/Library/texmf/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 262, version
               `2009/07/21' of package kvoptions,
               but only version
               `2007/10/18 v3.0 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)'
               is available.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4284 \DeclareLocalOptions
                           {%

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4285   a
          4paper,a5paper,b5paper,letterpaper,legalpaper,executivepaper%
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems that you have several old packages in your personal tree; rename `~/Library/texmf` to something else and then retry.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! Your log extract suggests you've got various 'local' files in `~/Library/texmf` which are probably conflicting with your updated install. What happens if you move them out of the way?

Comment: Thank you both for the good suggestion; this did indeed fix my  problem.  I had no idea that there was this possibility of conflict between my personal tree in Library, and the "real" files.  It's not clear to me how my personal tree got there in the first place, but I'm happy that I can now compile without these errors.

Answer (score 2):

There are three places where TeX Live looks for files; in order from least to highest priority they are

- `/usr/local/texlive/<year>/texmf-dist`, *aka* `TEXMFMAIN`
- `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local`, *aka* `TEXMFLOCAL`
- `~/texmf` (generic TeX Live) or `~/Library/texmf` (MacTeX), *aka* `TEXMFHOME`

The first location is only acted upon by `tlmgr` or utilities based on it, such as TeX Live Utility on Mac OS X.

The second location is good for files pertaining to packages or fonts that are not included in TeX Live for licensing reasons; it's a system administrator's responsibility to act on it. Files in it are accessible to all users.

The third location, which has the highest priority, can be read only by the account owner (the `~` above stands for the home directory, in your case `/Users/stmv`).

The extract from your log file shows that `kvoptions.sty` is located in `TEXMFHOME`, you probably downloaded a newer version than the one in TeX Live 2007 and unzipped it in that location.

When LaTeX is ordered to look for `kvoptions.sty` it doesn't do version checking, but only matches file names. Since it finds the file in the highest priority tree, it stops its search and loads the file.

Temporary solution: rename the folder `~/Library/texmf` to something else (say `~/Library/texmf-obsolete`), which will disable it. Then create a new `~/Library/texmf` folder where you'll transfer only those old files that are really necessary and are not older than distributed files.

For instance, in my own `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex` folder I keep only my private class files and I have an experimental format in `~/Library/texmf/web2c/pdftex`.